# Blue question mark on SQL server and SQL server agent?

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2019

I just installed MS SQL server 2017 on MS Server 2019. All installation process were fine. Using SSMS 18 access SQL server locally was fine, no issue at all.

But when I use SSMS 18 connecting SQL server remotely as sa I got a blue question mark on SQL server and SQL server agent.

I done a lot of researches and followed all suggestions, seems like none of "fix" can fix this issue. I never see this on previous version of SQL servers.

Is there anyone else get the same issue?

[image]

Comment: Try clicking the + symbol to expand it...

Comment: it wont change anything

Comment: It's not supposed to change anything. It's supposed to show you more detail.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176666/blue-icon-with-question-mark-what-does-it-mean

Comment: I tried all those suggestions without any luck before I posted my question.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found this issue can be caused by using an FQDN when connecting to the SQL server in SSMS. So if you've tried everything above and its still not working try...

Adding an entry for the SQL server to your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) with the IP address and just the server name, not FQDN. Then try connecting to the SQL server again in SSMS using just the server name works as expected.